# Using custom bundle in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase

Tags: android, android-testing

i am trying to write a test for my android application.
I have an activity which initializes couple of text fields from the Bundle passed to it in the onCreate() method (in the real case, the data has been put in the bundle from another activity)

I have written a test which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 but i cannot find a way to inject a custom Bundle in the test

could anyone assist pls?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#launchActivity%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20android.os.Bundle%29) which receives a `Bundle` as an argument. Note also that `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` extends `InstrumentationTestCase` and you should invoke `launchActivity()` before or instead of `getActivity()`.